# Http get response no populating in subscribe

Tags: angular

In angular5 working with http calls, made one service,

> app.service.ts

```
userDetail(userName) {
    return this.http
      .get(this.bioUrl + userName)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

> detail.component.ts

```
this.appService.search(this.searchTerm$)
  .subscribe(results => {
    this.results = results.results;
    this.result = results.items[0];
    console.log(results);
    console.log(this.result);
    console.log(this.result.owner.login) // Getting error


    this.appService.userDetail(this.result.owner.login) //Getting error
      .subscribe(bioData => {
        this.bioData = bioData;

        console.log(bioData);
      })

    this.appService.repoSearch(this.result.owner.login)
      .subscribe(repos => {
        this.repos = repos;

        console.log(repos);
      })
});
```

**error TS2339: Property 'owner' does not exist on type 'Object'.**

Sometimes compiling done nicely, but when executing calls console errors happening. Angular Build is not happening getting the above error.

Can someone help me to achieve?

Thanks,

Comment: What is the content of ``results.items[0]`` ?

Comment: results variable contains array of items, so i have taken first element.

Comment: You have to verify that you have the property ``owner`` inside ``results.items[0]`` otherwise you can't access it. you can test if you have that property first before accessing it by using ``hasOwnProperty``.

Comment: have you gone through the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response)

Comment: Please post the result of `console.log(results);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `map(res => res.json())` I assume that you use the old, deprecated `Http` class instead of the new `HttpClient` (You should switch over if you are startign a new project)

Your issue occurs because the type returned by `res.json()` is object, which does not contain any properties.

You need to explicitly declare the return type of the userDetails method

```
userDetail(userName) : Observable<any> { //Just to make it clear
    return this.http
      .get(this.bioUrl + userName)
      .map(res => res.json() as any); //<== as any
  }
```

You can also declare the type of retrieved data in your subscribe method

```
this.appService.search(this.searchTerm$)
  .subscribe((results : any)=> {
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make API call as async i.e use Observable.

- Import observable rxjs
- userDetail(username): observable {}

Angular Http request support default JSON further as a response, so you can remove map function

Now in view component write,

```
{{ bioData | json}}
```

I have updated the example have a look,

`app.apiService.ts`:

```
userDetail(userName): Observable<any>{
    const url = `${this.url}/user/login`+userName;
    return this.http.get(url, { headers: "If require" })
  }
```

app.component.ts:

```
method(){
  this.appService.userDetail(this.result.owner.login) //Getting error
      .subscribe(bioData => {

            /* for testing purpose, we will create our own response */

            /* array response */
            bioData = [{
                "name": "User Name",
                "age": "23"
            }]

            /* object response */
            bioData = {
                "name": "User Name",
                "age": "23"
            }

        this.bioData = bioData;
      },
      error => { 
        console.log("Error occur while api call")
      })
}
```

app.component.html

- to validate you have receive print api row response

  {{bioData | json}}
- if response if array then you have write

  > {{user.name}}
  >
  > {{user.age}}
  >
  > ```
  > <div *ngIf="bioData">
  >       <p>{{bioData.name}}</p>
  >       <p>{{bioData.age}}</p>
  >   </div>
  > ```

Comment: so now what is returned by `http` call as a response?